# Send ListCalendarView api with delta but always get 504 unknown error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have some problems when I use Microsoft Graph to track event changes with `deltalink`.

Here is my request:

```
GET /user/{id}/calendars/{id}/calendarView/delta?startDateTime=2018-01-01T00:00:00Z&endDateTime=2019-01-01T00:00:00Z

Prefer: odata.maxpagesize=1
```

I get a successful response the first time but when I follow the `nextlink` from the response I get `504` error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "93ad3434-5de2-465d-9552-5a93d001939f",
            "date": "2018-12-18T08:31:34"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `nextLink` look like? And are you sure you're getting a `nextLink`? Keep in mind, the final page will contain a `deltaLink` rather than a `nextLink`.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure what I get is `nextLink`. It looks like that `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${user_id}/calendars/${calendar_id}/calendarView/delta?$skiptoken=R0usmcdvmMuZCBYV0hguCLTzooWy4gxFlUrHT07cwkt4MM2Orqfz6l8bYjb6kApZph9GmKq5aTE6d6wSEQRi3Y7VHWpoMRqaCyq_1co-e32dZgfWMDweKauJG5Xw72wxZq4oxn0qXoJzJRnTXgu1qn9bt4Avw-v9_cTRiUUpgeZyX99zTgAZcltLeV0E4jePDgATyVkLWyidBIZzx8NigA.ivXTEIC5UXigGLo4HMJ_JrUpHIzVo7L7w1SwgL4v2kk`